# Power requirements for offset motor or other forms of vibration

Tags: power, motor, vibration

I need to generate vibrations to provide tactile feedback.  The device has minimal power available.  What type of power do offset motors require?  Are there other forms of vibration that can use less power?

Comment: Find the suitable motor(s) then find the specs in their datasheet(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiny motors used in such products as cellphones require about 200-250 mW minimum.